# cxf-xjc-plugin not generating java classes due to collision in ObjectFactory class

Tags: xsd, jaxb, maven-plugin, jaxb2, cxf-xjc-plugin

I got no class generated with **cxf-xjc maven plugin for Java** due to the following error:

> [ERROR] **Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
>   line 21 of**
>   file:/C:/../IdeaProjects/CXFDocInstanceGenerator/XSDToClassGenerator/src/main/resources/IntegralAdmission_bis.xsd

there are 3 xsds involved in the generation

- PExGeneraReport_bis.xsd (that uses the other two bellow)
- PartialAdmission_bis.xsd
- IntegralAdmission_bis.xsd

the last two xsd are generating the conflict on the following element:

```
<xs:group name="RootGroup">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="modulo" type="Modulo">
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

**contained in both xsds (PartialAdmission_bis.xsd and IntegralAdmission_bis.xsd**)

I used the following **last external binding condition** : to solve the problem (together with a lot of other tries) without success!

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="IntegralAdmission_bis.xsd">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='modulo']">
        <jxb:factoryMethod name="ModuloAccoglimentoIntegrale"/>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

beside factoryMethod name i use also **jxb:class and jxb:elementName** without success. **No classes are generated**

Changing the element name in one xsd setting:

> xs:element name="***moduloIA***" type="Modulo"

solves the problem but i need to maintain 'modulo' as the name of the xml element  for the marshalling and so **I need to change only the binding to java classes or method name! Any Idea on the correct binding to set to solve the problem?**

As asked by in the comments by @lexicore, I report hereafter an [mcve] of the project:
the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>CXFDocInstanceGenerator</groupId>
    <artifactId>MCVE_XSDToClassGenerator</artifactId>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.9</source>
                        <target>1.9</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extensions>
                        <extension>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins:cxf-xjc-dv:2.3.0</extension>
                    </extensions>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceRoot>
                            <xsdOptions>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/PExGeneraReport_bis.xsd</xsd>
                                    <!--bindingFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/dgPEXGR.xjb</bindingFile-->
                                    <extension>true</extension>
                                </xsdOption>
                            </xsdOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

the main xsd to bind **PExGeneraReport_bis.xsd**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:aci="urn://IntegralAdmission_bis"
           xmlns:acp="urn://PartialAdmission_bis"
           xmlns="urn://GenerateReport"
           targetNamespace="urn://GenerateReport"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
>
    <xs:import namespace="urn://IntegralAdmission_bis" schemaLocation="IntegralAdmission_bis.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="urn://PartialAdmission_bis" schemaLocation="PartialAdmission_bis.xsd"/>

    <xs:element name="root" type="Root"/>

    <xs:complexType name="Root">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="frontespizioPostel" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:group ref="RootGroup"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:group name="RootGroup">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:group ref="aci:RootGroup"/>
                <xs:group ref="acp:RootGroup"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <!--xs:element name="metadati" type="Metadati"/-->
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>

</xs:schema>
```

- the first imported xsd **IntegralAdmission_bis.xsd**

  ```
  <xs:element name="root" type="Root"/>

  <xs:complexType name="Root">
      <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="frontespizioPostel" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:group ref="RootGroup"/>
      </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:group name="RootGroup">
      <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="modulo" type="Modulo">
          </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>

  <xs:complexType name="Modulo">
      <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="denominazioneAzienda" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="indirizzo" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="pecAzienda" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="dataProvvedimento" type="xs:date"/>
          <xs:element name="tipoPrestazione" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="numeroProtocollo" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="numeroProvvedimento" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="annoProvvedimento" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="dataPresentazione" type="xs:date"/>
      </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  ```

The second one conflicting with the xsd above (IntegralAdmission_bis.xsd) **PartialAdmission_bis.xsd**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jxb:version="2.0"
    xmlns="urn://PartialAdmission_bis"
    targetNamespace="urn://PartialAdmission_bis"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="root" type="Root"/>

    <xs:complexType name="Root">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="frontespizioPostel" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:group ref="RootGroup"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:group name="RootGroup">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="modulo" type="Modulo">
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>

    <xs:complexType name="Modulo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="denominazioneAzienda" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="indirizzo" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="pecAzienda" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="dataProvvedimento" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="tipoPrestazione" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="numeroProtocollo" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="numeroProvvedimento" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="annoProvvedimento" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="dataPresentazione" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="causale" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Binding file:

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="IntegralAdmission_bis.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='modulo']">
            <jxb:factoryMethod name="ModuloAccoglimentoIntegrale"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Project directories:

[image]

Comment: That element should be a separate xsd to be included in other xsd files.

Comment: I don't have power on the xsds. Separating the element in an another xsd i change the namespace to which it belongs also. Isn't it? In such way i can have a validation error on the server that share me those xsd i think

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which would reproduce the problem. I have typically solved this precisely with `jaxb:factoryMethod` or `jaxb:property` bindings. In your case the XPath binding `//xs:element[@name='modulo']` seems overly broad to me. So *maybe* you have customized *both* `modulo` elements with the same factory method - so that they are still conflicting at the end. Create an [MCVE], this will be half the deal.

Comment: Is there a way to share friendly the mcve (without pasting all the code here)?

Comment: I updated the question for now